# How to get ths parts out of url via RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, url

I have two urls:

```
http://sp2013/sites/1234
```

and

```
http://sp2013/pwa/projectsites/projectdetails.aspx?projuid=1234-123-123-123456-123456
```

I want to get from the first url the last part (always a number)

```
1234
```

and from the second url also the last part (guid)

```
1234-123-123-123456-123456
```

How could i achieve this through RegEx or maybe with string operations in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string s = "http://sp2013/sites/1234";
var firstURLlastPart = new Uri(s).Segments.Last();

string s = "http://sp2013/pwa/projectsites/projectdetails.aspx?projuid=1234-123-123-123456-123456";
var secondURLlastPart = s.Split('=').Last();
```

Comment: thnx it work for me also

Answer (score 1):

Just split at `'/'` and take the last chunk for the first case.

```
str.Split('/').Last()
```

Split at `'='` and take last chunk for second case

```
str.Split('=').Last()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!\/|\=).[-0-9]+$
```

It's working for both. But it also accepts if in first example will be number in format like this:

```
12345-4568
```